# Parsing SOAP Response

Tags: apex, soap-api, force.com, soap

My SOAP response has some tags which are repeating. For e.g. below, the Identifier tag is repeating for different types of Identifiers. I want to extract the ME Number and DEA Number from this response.

I have been able to reach the Identifier tag using below -

```
    if (awr.getname() == 'Identifier') {
      system.debug('Identifier Block - ' + awr);

      dom.XmlNode [] IdentifierDtls = awr.getchildren();
      system.debug('Identifier Dtls - ' + IdentifierDtls);
```

How do I get to ME Number and DEA Number? The below code gives me 'ME Number' as text. I want the corresponding number which is present inside 
tag 'IdentifierValueText'

```
for (dom.XmlNode idntf : IdentifierDtls) {
    if (idntf.getname() == 'IdentifierTypeDescription')
    if (idntf.gettext() == 'ME Number')
    System.debug(idntf.gettext())
```

SOAP Response

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <ns0:getHCPApprovedExcludedProductsResponse xmlns:ns0="http://www.xyz.com/schemas/integration/ProductsModel.xsd">
                <ns0:MatchCount>1</ns0:MatchCount>
                <ns0:RecordCount>1</ns0:RecordCount>
                <ns0:ProductData>    


                 <ns0:Identifier>
                    <ns0:IdentifierTypeCode>202306</ns0:IdentifierTypeCode>
                    <ns0:IdentifierTypeDescription>ME Number</ns0:IdentifierTypeDescription>
                    <ns0:IdentifierValueText>xxxxx</ns0:IdentifierValueText>
                    <ns0:IdentifierStatusCode>0</ns0:IdentifierStatusCode>
                    <ns0:IdentifierStatusDescription>Active</ns0:IdentifierStatusDescription>
                    <ns0:IdentifierEffectiveDate>2008-02-15 22:07:54.0</ns0:IdentifierEffectiveDate>
                    <ns0:IdentifierDefaultFlag>Y</ns0:IdentifierDefaultFlag>
                    <ns0:DataSourceProviderID>200015</ns0:DataSourceProviderID>
                    <ns0:DataSourceProviderName>Comp A</ns0:DataSourceProviderName>
                    <ns0:ProfileID>111111</ns0:ProfileID>
                </ns0:Identifier>
                <ns0:Identifier>
                    <ns0:IdentifierTypeCode>202305</ns0:IdentifierTypeCode>
                    <ns0:IdentifierTypeDescription>DEA Number</ns0:IdentifierTypeDescription>
                    <ns0:IdentifierValueText>kkkkkk</ns0:IdentifierValueText>
                    <ns0:IdentifierStatusCode>0</ns0:IdentifierStatusCode>
                    <ns0:IdentifierStatusDescription>Active</ns0:IdentifierStatusDescription>
                    <ns0:IdentifierEffectiveDate>2008-02-16 12:39:24.0</ns0:IdentifierEffectiveDate>
                    <ns0:IdentifierDefaultFlag>Y</ns0:IdentifierDefaultFlag>
                    <ns0:DataSourceProviderID>200024</ns0:DataSourceProviderID>
                    <ns0:DataSourceProviderName>Comp A</ns0:DataSourceProviderName>
                    <ns0:ProfileID>222222</ns0:ProfileID>
                </ns0:Identifier>
                <ns0:Identifier>
                    <ns0:IdentifierTypeCode>202325</ns0:IdentifierTypeCode>
                    <ns0:IdentifierTypeDescription>Physician Number</ns0:IdentifierTypeDescription>
                    <ns0:IdentifierValueText>yyyyy</ns0:IdentifierValueText>
                    <ns0:IdentifierStatusCode>0</ns0:IdentifierStatusCode>
                    <ns0:IdentifierStatusDescription>Active</ns0:IdentifierStatusDescription>
                    <ns0:IdentifierEffectiveDate>2011-11-16 20:44:42.0</ns0:IdentifierEffectiveDate>
                    <ns0:IdentifierDefaultFlag>Y</ns0:IdentifierDefaultFlag>
                    <ns0:DataSourceProviderID>200069</ns0:DataSourceProviderID>
                    <ns0:DataSourceProviderName>Comp A</ns0:DataSourceProviderName>
                    <ns0:ProfileID>3333333</ns0:ProfileID>
                </ns0:Identifier>
                <ns0:Identifier>
                    <ns0:IdentifierTypeCode>202300</ns0:IdentifierTypeCode>
                    <ns0:IdentifierTypeDescription>SFA ID</ns0:IdentifierTypeDescription>
                    <ns0:IdentifierValueText>zzzzzz</ns0:IdentifierValueText>
                    <ns0:IdentifierStatusCode>0</ns0:IdentifierStatusCode>
                    <ns0:IdentifierStatusDescription>Active</ns0:IdentifierStatusDescription>
                    <ns0:IdentifierEffectiveDate>2003-02-14 20:13:47.0</ns0:IdentifierEffectiveDate>
                    <ns0:IdentifierDefaultFlag>Y</ns0:IdentifierDefaultFlag>
                    <ns0:DataSourceProviderID>200078</ns0:DataSourceProviderID>
                    <ns0:DataSourceProviderName>Comp A</ns0:DataSourceProviderName>
                    <ns0:ProfileID>444444</ns0:ProfileID>
                </ns0:Identifier>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your posted XML does not appear to be complete. You should have a parent node which lists the namespace. Something like:

```
<xml xmlns:ns0="http://ns0">
```

Assuming you have that, here is an anonymous script that demonstrates how you might use `getChildElement(name, namespace)` here:

```
String xml = '<xml xmlns:ns0="http://ns0"><ns0:Identifier><ns0:IdentifierTypeCode>202306</ns0:IdentifierTypeCode><ns0:IdentifierTypeDescription>MENumber</ns0:IdentifierTypeDescription><ns0:IdentifierValueText>xxxxx</ns0:IdentifierValueText><ns0:IdentifierStatusCode>0</ns0:IdentifierStatusCode><ns0:IdentifierStatusDescription>Active</ns0:IdentifierStatusDescription><ns0:IdentifierEffectiveDate>2008-02-1522:07:54.0</ns0:IdentifierEffectiveDate><ns0:IdentifierDefaultFlag>Y</ns0:IdentifierDefaultFlag><ns0:DataSourceProviderID>200015</ns0:DataSourceProviderID><ns0:DataSourceProviderName>CompA</ns0:DataSourceProviderName><ns0:ProfileID>111111</ns0:ProfileID></ns0:Identifier><ns0:Identifier><ns0:IdentifierTypeCode>202305</ns0:IdentifierTypeCode><ns0:IdentifierTypeDescription>DEANumber</ns0:IdentifierTypeDescription><ns0:IdentifierValueText>kkkkkk</ns0:IdentifierValueText><ns0:IdentifierStatusCode>0</ns0:IdentifierStatusCode><ns0:IdentifierStatusDescription>Active</ns0:IdentifierStatusDescription><ns0:IdentifierEffectiveDate>2008-02-1612:39:24.0</ns0:IdentifierEffectiveDate><ns0:IdentifierDefaultFlag>Y</ns0:IdentifierDefaultFlag><ns0:DataSourceProviderID>200024</ns0:DataSourceProviderID><ns0:DataSourceProviderName>CompA</ns0:DataSourceProviderName><ns0:ProfileID>222222</ns0:ProfileID></ns0:Identifier><ns0:Identifier><ns0:IdentifierTypeCode>202325</ns0:IdentifierTypeCode><ns0:IdentifierTypeDescription>PhysicianNumber</ns0:IdentifierTypeDescription><ns0:IdentifierValueText>yyyyy</ns0:IdentifierValueText><ns0:IdentifierStatusCode>0</ns0:IdentifierStatusCode><ns0:IdentifierStatusDescription>Active</ns0:IdentifierStatusDescription><ns0:IdentifierEffectiveDate>2011-11-1620:44:42.0</ns0:IdentifierEffectiveDate><ns0:IdentifierDefaultFlag>Y</ns0:IdentifierDefaultFlag><ns0:DataSourceProviderID>200069</ns0:DataSourceProviderID><ns0:DataSourceProviderName>CompA</ns0:DataSourceProviderName><ns0:ProfileID>3333333</ns0:ProfileID></ns0:Identifier><ns0:Identifier><ns0:IdentifierTypeCode>202300</ns0:IdentifierTypeCode><ns0:IdentifierTypeDescription>SFAID</ns0:IdentifierTypeDescription><ns0:IdentifierValueText>zzzzzz</ns0:IdentifierValueText><ns0:IdentifierStatusCode>0</ns0:IdentifierStatusCode><ns0:IdentifierStatusDescription>Active</ns0:IdentifierStatusDescription><ns0:IdentifierEffectiveDate>2003-02-1420:13:47.0</ns0:IdentifierEffectiveDate><ns0:IdentifierDefaultFlag>Y</ns0:IdentifierDefaultFlag><ns0:DataSourceProviderID>200078</ns0:DataSourceProviderID><ns0:DataSourceProviderName>CompA</ns0:DataSourceProviderName><ns0:ProfileID>444444</ns0:ProfileID></ns0:Identifier></xml>';
DOM.Document document = new DOM.Document();
document.load(xml);

for (DOM.XmlNode node : document.getRootElement().getChildren())
{
    DOM.XmlNode description = node.getChildElement('IdentifierTypeDescription', 'http://ns0');
    DOM.XmlNode value = node.getChildElement('IdentifierValueText', 'http://ns0');

    if (description != null && value != null)
    {
        system.debug(description.getText() + ' = ' + value.getText());
    }
}
```

Which gives me a readable log:

> USER_DEBUG [12]|DEBUG|MENumber = xxxxx
>   USER_DEBUG [12]|DEBUG|DEANumber = kkkkkk
>   USER_DEBUG [12]|DEBUG|PhysicianNumber = yyyyy
>   USER_DEBUG [12]|DEBUG|SFAID = zzzzzz

Comment: Excellent! Thanks Adrian! I was trying to overcomplicate it somehow. Thanks again